# Haskell: Algebraic data vs Tuple

Tags: haskell, types, tuples

```
data Ray = Ray Vector Vector
```

or

```
type Ray = (Vector, Vector)
```

Which is preferred in idiomatic haskell? Why should I use one over the other?
I don't care about performance.

It seems to make little difference with functions, e.g.:

```
trace :: Ray -> …

trace (Ray x d) = …
-- OR
trace (x, d) = …
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `data` version is preferred as it more clearly indicates the intent of the programmer — by creating a new type, you are pointing out to all that this is not merely a tuple, but a meaningful semantic entity, a `Ray`.

That then makes it possible to lean on the type system further, with custom instances for `Ray`, and optimizations not possible in tuples.

Comment: Right. And a critical point about types: they're about so much more than representation of data; they characterize useful structure.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. `type` is really just for a synonym, not a new data type. But the line has to be drawn somewhere—`type Colour = (Int, Int, Int)` would be appropriate, right?

Comment: No, for performance reasons it makes more sense to have a packed vector type for Color, as in the color package -- meaningful types like this can be optimized and specialized. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/colour/2.3.3/doc/html/src/Data-Colour-Internal.html#Colour

Comment: What would be an example use of a tuple, then?

Comment: Tuples are useful for temporary and intermediate data types that are not visible to other modules, or for collections of things that are logically related, but only "suporting actors" in a module.

Comment: @Mk12 Remember, `type Colour = (Int, Int, Int)` would be indistinguishable from `type Position = (Int, Int, Int)` for positions in 3-dimensional integer-coordinate spaces. But you probably don't intend for your functions that operate on positions to also operate on colours.

Answer (score 7):

You might also consider a third option that is kind of a combination of the two: `newtype`

```
newtype Ray = Ray (Vector, Vector)
```

Algebraic datatypes, in my opinion, are used in situations when you have multiple alternatives, or in cases when you need the type to be recursive, containing itself. But it might be overkill for something like this.

Don Stewart pointed out that making a type synonym to tuple is the same as using that tuple type directly; type synonyms have no identity of their own. So the type checker would not be able to distinguish between your type and a tuple, and so it cannot check that you're using the type where you want. Also, it would have the exact same instances as a tuple.

A `newtype` allows you to use the same underlying type as the tuple; but it's a separate type to the type checker, with separate instances.

Comment: This seems to be less common than using the curried form.  Perhaps only because it is more punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

A fourth alternative I found quite convenient are records:

```
data Ray = Ray { from, to :: Vector }
```

They have basically all the features of "normal" ADTs, but with some additional syntactical sugar. Especially they make it easier to get partially modified copies of a value. It's true that records are too limited in some situations, but then you can go further with "improved versions" like [fclabels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-1.1.1.1).