# Product type convert to tuple

Tags: haskell

I've got this

```
data Pair = P Int Double deriving Show
myP1 = P 1 2.0
getPairVal (P i d) = (i,d)
getPairVal' (P i d) = (,) i d
```

which work, both producing `(1,2.0)`. Is there any way to make a straight `(,) myP1` work? But then this would require some sort of "cast" I'm guessing.

```
data Pair2 = P2 (Int, Double) deriving Show
```

is a tuple version that is "handier" sort of

```
myP21 = (5,5.0)
```

So what would be the advantage of a product type like `Pair` with or without a tuple type definition? I seem to remember SML having a closer relationship, i.e., every product type was a tuple type. In math, anything that's a "product" produces a tuple. Haskell apparently not.

Comment: related (edited. not really duplicate) [types - Haskell: Algebraic data vs Tuple - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628352/haskell-algebraic-data-vs-tuple) but...

Comment: @user202729 I don't really agree. That's someone asking how to design their own program; this question is about how the language defines products.

Comment: Try not to ask 2 questions in one? The other question "why doesn't `(,) myP1` work" — because the standard doesn't allow that... (why should it work anyway?)?

Comment: What do you think the type of `(,)` is?

Comment: `(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)` but is there a way to "cast" it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why shouldn't a straight (,) myP1 work?

Well, `(,)` is a function that takes two values and makes a tuple out of them. `P 1 2.0` is *not* two values: it is a single value of type `Pair`, which contains two fields. But `(,) (P 1 2.0)` is a well-typed expression: it has built the left half of a tuple, and needs one more argument for the right half. So:

```
let mkTuple = (,) (P 1 2.0) 
in mkTuple "hello"
```

evaluates to

```
(P 1 2.0, "hello")
```

Why should we define types like `Pair` instead of using tuples? user202729 linked to [Haskell: Algebraic data vs Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628352/haskell-algebraic-data-vs-tuple) in a comment, which is a good answer to that question.

But one other approach you could use would be to define a `newtype` wrapping a tuple, so that you have a distinct named type, but the same runtime representation as a tuple:

```
newtype Pair2 = P2 (Int, Double) deriving Show
```

If you use `newtype` instead of `data`, you *do* get a simple conversion function, which you might choose to think of as a cast: [`Data.Coerce.coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce). With that, you could write

```
myP21 = coerce (5, 5.0)
```

and vice versa. This approach is primarily used when you want new typeclass instances for existing types. If you need a new domain type composed of two values, I'd still encourage you to default to using a `data` type with two fields unless there is a compelling reason not to.